# Find the point where the curve $\big(x(t),y(t)\big)=(t^2-1,t^3-t)$ crosses itself

Tags: calculus, parametric

Consider the curve defined by $x(t)=t^2-1$ and $y(t)=t^3-t.$

Find the point where the curve crosses itself.

I know that the curve will cross itself if there are two distinct values, say $t_1$ and $t_2$, such that $x(t_1)=x(t_2)$ and $y(t_1)=y(t_2).$

I have used this and have come down to $$t_1^2=t_2^2\\\text{ and }\\t_1^3-t_1=t_2^3-t_2.$$

I'm not sure how to solve these for $t_1$and $t_2$ though.

Comment: The first equation gives you $t_1=-t_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As remarked in the comments, the first equation leaves out two possibilities:
\begin{equation}
t_1=\pm t_2
\end{equation}
$t_1=t_2$ is trivial, so look at the other. Plugging in $t_1=-t_2$ in the second equation, you get
\begin{equation}
t_1^3=t_1
\end{equation}
which leaves you with three values, $t=-1,0,1$. So either $t_1=t_2=0$ (trivial), or $t_1=1$, $t_2=-1$: the solution only makes sense if $t_1\neq t_2$. So plug in either $t=1$ or $t=-1$ to get the self-intersection point!

Comment: The graph from WolframAlpha shows the curve intersects itself at $x=0$ and not at $1$ or $-1$. Check it out <a href="http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+of+x%28t%29+%3D+t%5E2+-1%2C+y%28t%29+%3D+t%5E3-t&x=0&y=0">here</a>.

Comment: yes, that's the value you get for $t=\pm 1$!

Comment: Oops! My bad. I was using a different method for solving so got off the track a bit. Thought you were saying intersection is at $x= \pm 1$.

Comment: Conclusion: a geometrical problem should, as is possible, be accompanied by a graphical exploration/verification, which, sadly, is not the case, although we live in a world where we have wonderful tools to do it